# Piping output to cut

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to get the name of the shell executing a script.

Why does

```
echo $(ps | grep $PPID) | cut -d" " -f4
```

work while

```
echo ps | grep $PPID | cut -d" " -f4
```

does not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason is that

```
echo ps
```

just prints out the string `ps`; it doesn't run the program `ps`. The corrected version of your command would be:

```
ps | grep $PPID | cut -d" " -f4
```

**Edited to add:** paxdiablo points out that `ps | grep $PPID` includes a lot of whitespace that will get collapsed by `echo $(ps | grep $PPID)` (since the result of `$(...)`, when it's not in double-quotes, is split by whitespace into separate arguments, and then `echo` outputs all of its arguments separated by spaces). To address this, you can use `tr` to "squeeze" repeated spaces:

```
ps | grep $PPID | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5
```

or you can just stick with what you had to begin with. :-)

Comment: For some reason, echo $(ps | grep $PPID) | cut -d" " -f4 will give me "bash" while ps | grep $PPID | cut -d" " -f4 just gives me an empty space

Comment: Not quite. The first version has the extra effect of collapsing spaces.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Good point! I'll see about editing my answer . . .

Answer (score 7):

The first line:

```
echo $(ps | grep $PPID) | cut -d" " -f4
```

says:

- Execute `ps | grep $PPID` in a sub-shell
- Return the output - which will be something like this:

  ```
  3559 pts/1 00:00:00 bash
  ```

  and then use that output as the first parameter of echo - which, in practice, means just echo the output
- Then run `cut -d" " -f4` on that - which gives you the command name in this case

The second command:

```
echo ps | grep $PPID | cut -d" " -f4
```

says:

- Echo string `ps`
- Grep that string for `$PPID` - this will never return anything, as `$PPID` contains a number, so it will never be `ps`. Thus, grep returns nothing
- Execute `cut -d" " -f4` with input of the previous command - which is nothing, so you get nothing

Answer (score 2):

I think if you run just `echo ps` on its own, you'll see why your pipe doesn't work:

```
$ echo ps
ps
```

Instead, check `$0`. Note that it might be `-bash` or `bash`, depending if it is a *login shell*. (Well, any shell -- not just `bash` -- but the *hyphen* is added if the shell is a login shell.)